# iOS Urban Airship de-register notifications

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

Good Day,

The API on iOS for Urban Airship for registration is available. Basically it is just

```
[[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

However, there doesnt seem to be any API to de-register the device from receiving notifications at all. What can I do? I mean I could "register" it to a "inactive" alias account but this doesnt seem very good.

Comment: recieving notification can be stopped from app settings page.Is it enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
[[UAirship shared] unRegisterDeviceToken];
```

Here's what apple Documentation says about this method

```
Unregister for notifications received from Apple Push Service.
- (void)unregisterForRemoteNotifications
Discussion

You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a new version of the application drops support for remote notifications. Users can temporarily prevent applications from receiving remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings application. Applications unregistered through this method can always re-register.
Availability

    Available in iOS 3.0 and later.

See Also

    – registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    – enabledRemoteNotificationTypes

Declared In
UIApplication.h
```

Comment: is this for Urban Airship?

Comment: yes check this link https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/11799-registering-and-unregistering-in-app-preferences